# df.plot - only scatter plot allowed

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, plot

I have two CSV files that I load into Pandas dataframe. Then I plot some columns to one graph. Somehow one graph can be whatever type (line, area, scatter, bar etc), but the other can only be scatter. Why is that?

Here is my working code. When I change in the last row kind="scatter" to kind="line" (or any other type), it does not plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('current_speed.csv', sep=';',
                 parse_dates={ 'datetime':['year','month','day','time_utc'] })

df1 = pd.read_csv('wind_speed.csv', sep=';',
                 parse_dates={ 'datetimex':['year','month','day','time_utc'] })

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

df.plot(x = 'datetime', y = 'curr_speed', color="blue",legend=False, ax= ax1,linewidth=1,alpha=0.4,kind="line")
df1.plot('datetimex', 'wind_speed',ax=ax2, kind="scatter")
```

Here are the data files:
wind_speed.csv

```
year;month;day;time_utc;wind_dir;wind_speed;wind_gust
2022;10;27;00:00;280;4.3;8.5
2022;10;27;01:00;268;6.4;8.3
2022;10;27;02:00;272;6.5;8.9
```

current_speed.csv

```
year;month;day;hour;min;sec;time_utc;curr_speed;curr_dir
2022;10;27;13;36;42;13:36;0.174;21.75
2022;10;27;14;36;42;14:36;0.195;38.42
2022;10;27;15;36;42;15:36;0.146;34.15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This allows you to choose whatever type you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

wind_speed_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [2022, 2022, 2022],
    'month': [10, 10, 10],
    'day': [27, 27, 27],
    'time_utc': ['00:00', '01:00', '02:00'],
    'wind_dir': [280, 268, 272],
    'wind_speed': [4.3, 6.4, 6.5],
    'wind_gust': [8.5, 8.3, 8.9]
})

current_speed_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [2022, 2022, 2022],
    'month': [10, 10, 10],
    'day': [27, 27, 27],
    'hour': [13, 14, 15],
    'min': [36, 36, 36],
    'sec': [42, 42, 42],
    'time_utc': ['13:36', '14:36', '15:36'],
    'curr_speed': [0.174, 0.195, 0.146],
    'curr_dir': [21.75, 38.42, 34.15]
})

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax2 = ax1.twinx()

wind_speed_df.plot(x='time_utc', y='wind_speed', ax=ax2, kind='line', color='red')

current_speed_df.plot(x='time_utc', y='curr_speed', ax=ax1, kind='line', color='blue')

ax1.set_xlabel('Time (UTC)')
ax1.set_ylabel('Current Speed (m/s)', color='blue')
ax2.set_ylabel('Wind Speed (m/s)', color='red')
plt.title('Current and Wind Speeds vs Time (UTC)')

plt.show()
```

[image]

or

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

wind_speed_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [2022, 2022, 2022],
    'month': [10, 10, 10],
    'day': [27, 27, 27],
    'time_utc': ['00:00', '01:00', '02:00'],
    'wind_dir': [280, 268, 272],
    'wind_speed': [4.3, 6.4, 6.5],
    'wind_gust': [8.5, 8.3, 8.9]
})

current_speed_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [2022, 2022, 2022],
    'month': [10, 10, 10],
    'day': [27, 27, 27],
    'hour': [13, 14, 15],
    'min': [36, 36, 36],
    'sec': [42, 42, 42],
    'time_utc': ['13:36', '14:36', '15:36'],
    'curr_speed': [0.174, 0.195, 0.146],
    'curr_dir': [21.75, 38.42, 34.15]
})

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax2 = ax1.twinx()

wind_speed_df.plot(x='time_utc', y='wind_speed', ax=ax2, kind='scatter', color='red')

current_speed_df.plot(x='time_utc', y='curr_speed', ax=ax1, kind='line', color='blue')

ax1.set_xlabel('Time (UTC)')
ax1.set_ylabel('Current Speed (m/s)', color='blue')
ax2.set_ylabel('Wind Speed (m/s)', color='red')
plt.title('Current and Wind Speeds vs Time (UTC)')

plt.show()
```

[image]

The reason that only scatter plot is allowed for df1 is because you are using ax2 for this plot, which is not compatible with some types of plots. The secondary y-axis is used for plots that have a different scale than the primary y-axis (ax1), such as scatter plots.